# pandas.DataFrame why use parenthesis to wrap operations to make bitwise comparison

Tags: python, pandas

A DataFrame is called c, and it has a column called price in which I want to know the rows with price equal to 2 or 3. And the code works here

```
c[(c['price'] == 2) | (c['price'] == 3)]
```

But doesn't work here:

```
c[c['price'] == 2 | c['price'] == 3]
```

and raises an exception:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

The only difference is in the second line of code, there's no parenthesis '()' wrapped to the operation. So why the parenthesis is so important?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- As per [Pandas: Boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

  - Another common operation is the use of boolean vectors to filter the data. The operators are: `|` for `or`, `&` for `and`, and `~` for `not`. These **must** be grouped by using parentheses, since by default Python will evaluate an expression such as `df['A'] > 2 & df['B'] < 3` as `df['A'] > (2 & df['B']) < 3`, while the desired evaluation order is `(df['A > 2) & (df['B'] < 3)`